# matlab - set tick label at origin

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

In generating plots with Matlab, when both the x and y minimum are zero, I prefer to have only one zero marking the origin rather than denoting it on both axes.

Matlab defaults to the latter, like so

[image: figure with 'double origin']

Whereas I want something more like this

[image: figure with 'single origin']

This can be done manually, but I'm trying to automate the process. Removing the `x` and `y` tick labels for `0` are obviously easy enough. However, I can't seem to access any handle for the position of the axis tick labels to properly position a text box for the 'new origin'. It seems the tick label offsets from the x and y axes may be somewhat constant in a given figure (in physical units, not normalized units), but I don't know if this is a standard across all figures or axes.

Any ideas?

I'm running Matlab 2014b.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simple way to do that:

```
% somthing to plot:
x = 0:0.1:2*pi;
y = abs(sin(x)+cos(x));
plot(x,y)

% get the handle for the current axes:
ax = gca;
% get the position of the zero tick on y-axis:
zeroYtick = ax.YAxis.TickValues==0;
% remove it (tick and lable)
ax.YAxis.TickValues(zeroYtick) = [];
```

The result:

[image: zero tick]

If you want the `0` to be offset a little to the left, so it will be at the corner of the plot, you can use annotation:

```
% get the position of the zero tick on x-axis:
zeroXtick = ax.XAxis.TickValues==0;
% remove it (tick and lable)
ax.XAxis.TickValues(zeroXtick) = [];
% place a new zero at the origin:
dim = [0.1 0.01 0.1 0.1];
annotation('textbox',dim,'String','0',...
    'FitBoxToText','on','LineStyle','none')
```

And you will get:

[image: zero tick 2]

The advantage in [`annotation`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/annotation.html) is that the origin always placed relative to the corner of the axes, and you don't need to know the values of the axes ticks to properly offset it.

---

**EDIT:**

For pre 2016a version you can use the following (I wrote it a little more compact):

```
ax = gca;
% remove the zero tick on y-axis (tick and lable):
ax.YTick(ax.YTick==0) = [];
% remove the zero tick on x-axis (tick and lable):
ax.XTick(ax.XTick==0) = [];
% place a new zero at the origin:
dim = [0.1 0.01 0.1 0.1];
annotation('textbox',dim,'String','0',...
    'FitBoxToText','on','LineStyle','none')
```

---

**EDIT 2:**

Another option to keep the `0` in place is to stick it to the axes. this is done by replacing the `Parent` with the axes handle. First, we need a handle to the annotation (continuing from the last edit):

```
t = annotation('textbox',dim,'String','0',...
    'FitBoxToText','on','LineStyle','none');
```

then we switch the `Parent` and set the new position:

```
t.Parent = ax;
t.Position(1:2) = -[0.2 0.1];
```

and finally, we super-glue it by converting the `Units` to pixels:

```
t.Units = 'Pixels';
```

Comment: This is exactly what I want, namely the `0` to be offset from the a little to the left. The annotation seems to do the trick, but if you then resize the figure, the `0` moves. Also, I'm assuming you are on some version later than 2014b because the graphics handles are different. I have no handle to ax.XAxis, etc. But that doesn't really mater, I can remove the tick labels, properly annotating the `0` is where I'm getting stuck.

Comment: @Brian, If you squeeze the figure too much then the `0` is not properly set, otherwise, I can resize it as much as I want and it sticks to its' place. Anyway, I added a version of the code for earlier versions of Matlab.

Comment: resizing still moves the `0` on my system. I'm not sure if you have different settings where it is not on yours, but as soon as I resize the figure the annotated `0` shifts around so as not to be located at the origin (note this happens even if the figure is resized only slightly). I certainly appreciate the answer, but as is it doesn't quite do what I'm looking for. I have tried adding the annotation after resizing the figure, with the same outcome, and tried resizing both with axis units in normalized and physical units.

Answer (score 0):

The following will exclude the first tick on yaxis without shifting the graph at all. You can ensure that the correct item is being removed by setting the axis limits, `ylim([0,upper_limit])` prior to removing the first one, or manually setting your yTicks, `set(h,'yTick',my_ticks)`. Note that `yTick` changes the position of the ticks, while `yTickLabel` will change the text appearing at each position of `yTick`

```
h = plot([0,1],[0,1]);
yTicks = get(h,'yTick');
set(h,'yTick',yTick(2:end));
```